# Операторы в python3.7 (pyglet)

Tags: python, python-3.x, синтаксис, декоратор

Увидел в документации **python** к библиотеке pyglet, такую строку `@window.event`

В **php**  знак `@` игнорирует ошибки, а за что означает знак `@` перед вызовом события окна в **python**?

Comment: Это декоратор https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators

Comment: спасибо тебе добрый человек. этот момент я упустил при изучении python